# How to parse this JSON format in android

Tags: java, json

The JSON is in this format

```
....
     "dummy": {
            "e": "numeric",
            "e2": "dum",
            "e3": "numeric",
            "e4": "numeric"
        },
        ,
        "name":[
        {
              "f1":"a",
              "f2":"b",
        }
      ],
....
```

**I want to get the value of f1 or f2**

Java code:

```
 try {
  JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(json);
  JSONArray Array2 = rootObject2.getJSONArray("name");
  for (int i=0; i<Array2.length(); i++)
{
      JSONObject venueJson2 = dataArray2.getJSONObject(i);
      venue.setSportTypes(venueJson2.getString("f1"));                     
    }
```

I have tried to use as JSON array and I get value as `null`, can anyone say what is the correct format to get the value.

Comment: Please post the java code that you have tried.

Comment: Do you already have a specific JSON library like Gson or Jackson? If so, don't you understand how to use them or haven't you chosen some library yet?

Comment: i dont have them, n i dnt knw them, can nrmal java not handle this ?

Comment: Then take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31743324/4014509) If this helps, you might want to close your question as duplicate ;) Otherwise please rephrase it, if there is a specific problem. *Edit:* No, there is no neat vanilla Java way.

Comment: You are missing the starting `{` character.  Without that you have no chance of understanding the JSON.  If you restore that character and then study json.org for about 10 minutes, then you might understand what's going on.

Comment: hi hot licks, i wanted to put dots, sorry i had forgotten

Comment: The JSON is not valid, check the JSON format here, http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: viggy, i knw it is not in exact format, i have just given part of it,thats y ...

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted is not an array that's why you get null. U can try:

```
HashMap<> foo = <Your JSON>
HashMap<String, String> bar = foo.get("dummy");
//get values from bar
ArrayList<> bar2 = foo.get("name");
HashMap<String, String> bar3 = bar2.get(0)
//get values from bar3
```

for this to work the 2nd "," before names has to be a typo tho